# Why is apt-get trying to remove certain packages when I install wine?

Tags: debian, apt, wine

I'm trying to install wine, which is software for running Windows applications. When I do `sudo apt-get install wine`, apt-get warns me that some packages are being removed.

1. Why would apt-get remove any packages to install a package?
2. It smells funny to me, since many of the packages it wants to remove are libreoffice packages, which would supposedly compete with Windows productivity software (which I'm NOT planning to install). Is this the reason? Would wine do nasty things like that?

Here's the output from running `apt-get install wine`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bind9-doc libasound2:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common chromium cups cups-bsd cups-client dbus dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
  libasound2:i386 libavformat53 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
  libfreetype6:i386 libgadu3 libgcrypt11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgnutls26 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgsm1:i386 libice6:i386
  libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-progs libjpeg8 libjpeg8:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libodbc1:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpng12-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.0:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libtiff4:i386 libtinfo5:i386 libuuid1:i386 libwine:i386 libwine-bin:i386
  libwine-gecko-1.4 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 openssh-client
  openssh-server openssl uuid-runtime wine-bin:i386
Suggested packages:
  apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom chromium-l10n cups-pdf xpp dovecot-gssapi dovecot-sieve dovecot-pgsql dovecot-mysql dovecot-sqlite dovecot-ldap
  dovecot-lmtpd dovecot-managesieved dovecot-solr libasound2-plugins:i386 rng-tools:i386 gpm:i386 libmyodbc:i386 odbc-postgresql:i386 tdsodbc:i386
  unixodbc-bin:i386 wine-doc:i386 libwine-cms:i386 libwine-sane:i386 libwine-ldap:i386 libwine-print:i386 libwine-openal:i386 libwine-gphoto2:i386
  ssh-askpass libpam-ssh keychain monkeysphere rssh molly-guard ufw
Recommended packages:
  uuid-runtime:i386 libv4l-0:i386 ttf-liberation:i386 libwine-gl:i386 libwine-alsa:i386 libwine-oss:i386 xml-core:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bind9 bind9utils cheese dlint dnsutils empathy gnome gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-nettool gnome-video-effects gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
  kde-standard kmail libcheese-gtk21 libcheese3 libfarstream-0.1-0 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libreoffice libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-evolution libreoffice-filter-binfilter
  libreoffice-filter-mobiledev libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-style-galaxy libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer libtelepathy-farstream2 lwresd mythes-en-us
  nautilus-sendto-empathy python-uno task-dns-server task-gnome-desktop telepathy-haze unoconv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libasound2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386
  libgsm1:i386 libice6:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libodbc1:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpng12-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libtiff4:i386 libtinfo5:i386 libuuid1:i386 libwine:i386 libwine-bin:i386 libwine-gecko-1.4
  libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 uuid-runtime wine wine-bin:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common chromium cups cups-bsd cups-client dbus dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
  libavformat53 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdbus-1-3 libgadu3 libgnutls26 libjpeg-progs libjpeg8
  libssl1.0.0 openssh-client openssh-server openssl
29 upgraded, 39 newly installed, 49 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
Need to get 121 MB of archives.
After this operation, 294 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

Comment: I agree, this does not seem normal. What version of debian do you think you are running? You may accidentally have a mixed system. Please post (as debugging info) the output of `apt-cache policy`, and also, the output of `apt-cache policy wine` in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often apt-get will prefer to remove dozens of packages instead of just updating a couple of other packages.

I usually run aptitude in interactive mode, select the package I want to install with + and then inspect what other packages might be broken by this action (jump to the next "broken" package with the 'b' key. Often just updating those (again with +) will resolve the problem with little hassle. When everything's resolved, hit 'g' for "go and do it". It will show a summary of what will happen (page through the complete list, it's colour-coded to help) and then hit 'g' again when satisfied.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install aptitude` and then `sudo aptitude install wine` for a more helpful error message.